Python script Why can't I register it after running it several times?
This is a script for registering an account, but I found it during testing. The first test was normal. The second time you run the test, you fail to commit. I don't know why. At first I thought it was the proxy IP, until I changed the proxy IP, and then it still didn't work, and then I tried to set the browser fingerprint. I used AdsPower fingerprint browser, found that it still does not work, may be before using selenium to register when detected is a robot in operation, then I changed to a more secure script way to register seleniumbase, but seleniumbase does not seem to have fingerprint settings, followed by the addition of selenium_stealth library to achieve some regional settings, until this test code, still can not solve the problem. The current account cannot be registered. I don't know why. Do you have any experience with this? Or what I can do to solve this problem! Here are some of the test code
def input_content(driver,user,name,password,number,email):
    common_xpath = '(//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section account-info-section"]/div[@class="container-xs centered"]/div[@class="form-table"]//div[@class="column large-6 medium-6 small-6"])'
    driver.type(f'{common_xpath}[1]//input', user)
    driver.type(f'{common_xpath}[2]//input', name)
    random_birthday = str('01012001')
    driver.type('(//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section account-info-section"]//div[@class="row"])[2]//input',
                random_birthday)
    email='dsdsaimx@gamil.com'
    number='18801928001'
    # email
    driver.type('((//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section"])[1]//input)[1]',email)
    # password
    driver.type('((//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section"])[1]//input)[2]', password)
    # password
    driver.type('((//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section"])[1]//input)[3]', password)
    # number
    driver.type('((//div[@role="main"]/div[@class="flow-section"])[2]//input)[1]', number)

def open_url():
    proxy='user:password@host:PORT'
    driver = Driver(uc=True,proxy=proxy)
    stealth(driver,
            languages=["pl-PL", "pl"],
            vendor="Google Inc.",
            platform="Win32",
            webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
            renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
            fix_hairline=True,
            )
    url = "https://appleid.apple.com/"
    driver.uc_open_with_reconnect(url, 7)
    driver.click('(//nav[@id="ac-localnav"]//div[@class="ac-localnav-menu"]//li)[2]/a')
    driver.sleep(5)
    # driver, user, name, password, number, email
    input_content(driver,'adimmx','daimmx','cixjzrnw@V25','1232','213')
    driver.sleep(100)
    driver.quit()

I tried using different proxy IPs, switching browser fingerprints, fingerprints here may not be particularly deep. Try using different libraries to evade robot detection. Still can't solve the problem. I want someone to help me point out where the problem is. Then I went to modify it. Thank you!

This cannot be the whole script.  It defines two functions, but those functions are not actually called, so running this script would do nothing.

Yes, this is just part of the test code. I posted the core code. The call runs without problems. The problem now is that when registering, it will prompt that the current account cannot be registered. I don't know what the reason is.
